# AJAX in Javascript - named callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, onreadystatechange

I am doing a very simple AJAX with javascript demo. My application has an AddCountry page, user selects a country and the states list is dynamically populated via AJAX.

The demo was working nicely until I decided to try something new. Instead of an anonymous callback with the `onreadystatechange` event handler, I used a named callback. It gives me this error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'status' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': the object's state must not be OPENED.
```

Here are two sample codes:

Common part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function createXHR(){
       if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
           return new XMLHttpRequest();
       else 
           return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
   }

   function getStates()
   {
       alert("inside getStates");
       var ajax = createXHR(); // step 1 : create XHR object
       alert("XHR:"+ajax);
       // step 2: creating the ajax request
       var inputVal = document.getElementById("country"); 
       var country = inputVal.value;
       alert("Value:"+country);
       ajax.open("GET","index.jsp?country="+country, true);  

       // sending the ajax request
       ajax.send(null);

       // step 4: monitoring for and updating the response
```

After that this code is not working:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxCallback();
         function ajaxCallback(){
             //alert("Response Received:"+ajax.status);

               if (ajax.status === 404)
                   alert("status 404");

               if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 404)
               { 
                   alert("Response Received; "+ajax.responseText);
                   document.getElementById("states").innerHTML = ajax.responseText; 
               }
          }
```

but this works :

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
    { document.getElementById("states").innerHTML = ajax.responseText; }
}
```

Can anybody let me know what is the error here?

Thanks in advance,
Navin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the function and assigning the response to onreadystatechange, rather than assigning your handler to the event. It should be:

`ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxCallback;`